# qml qt grabToImage get image bytes

Tags: image, qt, go, qml, byte

For some reason, saving a png back out from qml directly doesn't work. I have a qml UI on top of a Golang application. When I do

```
source.grabToImage(function(result){
    console.log("image: ", result.url)
if (!result.saveToFile(urlNoProtocol)){
    console.error('Unknown error saving to',urlNoProtocol);
} else {
    console.log("saved to " + urlNoProtocol)
}
```

I get an error saving out. The location to save the file is coming from a fileDialog and I preprocess it to remove the `file://` which I understand needs to be removed before using `saveToFile`. However I get an unknown error saving from the above code.

I suspect this is something to do with the qml being embedded in the binary application (perhaps to do with `qrc://` or something)

Anyway my current plan is to send the image to the golang backend and save it out from there, so my question is, how from `grabToImage` or `saveToFile` can I get the image bytes that I will then save?

N.B Using therecipe/qt for the interface between Golang and qml

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method for grabbing screen shots..

```
function performScreenShot(item, name) {
    if(typeof(item) === "undefined") {
        return;
    }
    else if(typeof(name) !== "string") {
        name = "screenshot.png"
    }

    item.grabToImage(function(result) {
        result.saveToFile(name);
    });
}
```

Usage example:-

```
performScreenShot(main, "screenshot-" + screenShotIndex + ".png")
```

Where main is my object id and screenShotIndex is something im incrementing so as not to override any previous capture.

Ensure that you have write permission on the device.